# How long do External HDD lasts?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I am planning on buying a 1TB Seagate External Hard Drive(non-SSD), but I am concerned about the life expectancy of the drive. How long do they last? Are they worth buying?

Comment: Drives fail, sometime in minutes, sometimes in years.  Look at the warranty that comes with the drive(s) you are considering; that's your best metric for this.

Comment: Why not look at one of the many studies of HDD with time, such as https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-reliability-stats-q1-2016/, and form your own opinion?

Comment: Couple related questions: [How reliable are 2.5" external hard drives?](http://superuser.com/questions/83768/how-reliable-are-2-5-external-hard-drives?rq=1), [Are there differences in life expectation for 1~2TB external (portable) HDD and external (desktop) HDD](http://superuser.com/questions/462200/are-there-differnces-in-life-expectation-for-12tb-external-portable-hdd-and-e?rq=1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my and my co-workers experience It is a complete wash. I have personally owned Seagate external's that have died within almost exactly a year and some that are still chugging 4 or 5 years later.

If you are after life expectancy and dependability I would recommend going for an SSD like the [samsung 500gb external](https://www.neweggbusiness.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9B-20-147-512&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleBiz-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleBiz-PC-_-pla-_-Solid%20State%20Disk%20-%20External-_-9B-20-147-512&gclid=Cj0KEQjw_qW9BRCcv-Xc5Jn-26gBEiQAM-iJhXAz7xEAGXTWVB6fDgcnVriWhortVUH6umC1sCcY5Q8aAh2E8P8HAQ). Which have been applauded for dependability and have a warranty of 3 years. While there internal 2.5" products like the vNand 500GB 850's have 10 year warranties.